# Permalink configuration in wordpress and how to?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, permalinks

Good day. I'm running my website on virtual host local which has the urls look like this :

```
1. Home page : www.vhost1.com/
2. Category Page (List of news) : www.vhost1.com/index.php/category/business
3. Article page (news detail) : www.vhost1.com/index.php/featured-article-4
```

I want to change these permalinks (hide the index.php) as

```
a. Category Page (List of news) : www.vhost1.com/category/business
b. Article page (news detail) : www.vhost1.com/categorty/business/featured-article-4
```

I tried setting up the permalinks on wp-admin panel but when I click on any category list or article, the website says that 'Object not found'. 
I had to add the 'index.php' between the permalinks so that it could redirect. 
Any way to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

To remove `index.php` from your Wordpress URL you will need to do two things.

The first step is updating the Permalinks within the Wordpress Dashboard.

Login to your **Wordpress Dashboard** and Click **Settings** > **Permalinks**. Under Common Settings, Select Custom Structure and in the text field enter **/%postname%/**

Click Save Changes

The second step is creating an .htaccess file which is then uploaded into the root location of the Wordpress site.

The `.htaccess` file will contain the below rules:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```